# What is the Lie group smooth structure of quaternions?

Tags: lie-groups, quaternions

It's obvious that Quaternions, (denote by $H$, without $0$) form a non-commutative group under multiplication ( it's even non commutative division algebra ). It seems that it's also obvious that Quaternions is a Lie Group, but somehow I don't understand what is the smooth map for $\mu: H \times H \rightarrow H$. Is the smooth map just a product of two quaternions, like $\mu(g,q)=gq$? Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 7):

Note that, for any Lie group, the product map $G \times G \to G$ is required to be smooth (it's not enough for some random map $G \times G\to G$ to be smooth; rather, the product map that you wrote down must be smooth).

One way to see that this holds for the non-zero quaternions is to embed the quaterinons in $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$. The multiplication map on $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is obviously smooth (it's a polynomial in the entries) and so its restriction to $H^\times$ is also smooth.

You could also check it directly. The non-zero quaternions look like $\mathbb{R}^4$ with an origin removed, so inherit a smooth structure from that. Again, the multiplication law is just a polynomial in the coefficients of $1, i, j, k$ with respect to this identification, and so is smooth.

Actually the quaternions are even a ring-object in the category of differential manifolds -- both the addition and multiplication structures are smooth.

Comment: I think you've already basically hit on this, but the unit quaternions are diffeomorphic to $SU_2$ and they are also isomorphic as Lie groups. Since  multiplication on $SU_2$ is smooth so too must multiplication on the unit quaternions be. Furthermore the quaternions admit the polar decomposition $q = re^{\Theta\mu}$, where $\mu$ is pure and $r$ is real, thus we construct $H$ as a union of nested hyperspheres to turn the unit quaternion / $SU_2$ Lie group isomorphism into an injective ring homomorphism from $H\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Greetings from the future. I have a group homomorphism from $\mathbb{H}^* \hookrightarrow \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$. How do you see that $\mathbb{H}^*$ inherits a smooth structure from the general linear group? Is it an open subset, or is there some other machinery at play?

Comment: hi @DEATH_CUBE_K... so you're coming from 2020 and this is the most important thought you have to communciate back to 2015?! It is closed on $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$. I guess in this answer I'm implicitly assuming that a closed subgroup of a Lie group is a Lie group; this is true but needs some proving.

Comment: as to why they're closed -- easiest to show all quaternions closed in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$. this is clear since they're a (real) linear subspace

Comment: Thanks for the info. I went a different route before I read your comment. You can realize $\mathbb{H}^*$ as the level set $\Phi^{-1}(I_2)$ where $\Phi:\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C}) \to M_2(\mathbb{C}), X \mapsto \text{det}(X)^{-1} X^*X$. The map is equivariant under certain right actions of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and hence constant rank by the equivariant map theorem. Then $\mathbb{H}^*$ is a properly embedded submanifold via the constant-rank level set theorem.